# c# hide (vertical/horizontal)lines when exporting from Xtragrid to Xlsx

Tags: c#

i have problem when export Xtragrid to xlsx the vertical line does not stop in the last row,how i can make them stop or how i can hide (vertical/horizontal)lines.
my code to export

```
  private void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SaveFileDialog saveDialog = new SaveFileDialog())
        {
            saveDialog.Filter = "Excel (2007-2019) (.xlsx)|*.xlsx |Word (2007-2019) (.docx)|*.docx |Pdf File (.pdf)|*.pdf |Html File (.html)|*.html";
            if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                string exportFilePath = saveDialog.FileName;
                string fileExtenstion = new FileInfo(exportFilePath).Extension;

                switch (fileExtenstion)
                {
                    case ".xlsx":
                        gridControl1.ExportToXlsx(exportFilePath);
                        break;
                    case ".docx":
                        gridControl1.ExportToDocx(exportFilePath);
                        break;
                    case ".pdf":
                        gridControl1.ExportToPdf(exportFilePath);
                        break;
                    case ".html":
                        gridControl1.ExportToHtml(exportFilePath);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

             }
        }
```

Comment: What is the type of `gridControl1` ? And what are you using , WinForms WPF ASP.NET ??

Comment: i am using DevExpress WinForms Grid Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used LayoutMode to achieve this

```
 if (saveDialog.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
  {

 XlsxExportOptionsEx options = new XlsxExportOptionsEx();
 options.LayoutMode = DevExpress.Export.LayoutMode.Table;                 
 string exportFilePath = saveDialog.FileName;
 string fileExtenstion = new FileInfo(exportFilePath).Extension;
 fileExtenstion = ".xlsx";
 options.BeforeExportTable += ea => {
 ea.Table.Style.Name = XlBuiltInTableStyleId.None;
  };
 gridControl2.ExportToXlsx(exportFilePath, options);
```